# Why don't we improve the design of the link to the about page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, new-users

I'm a user of Ask Ubuntu for more than 11 months, and just *today* I noticed the [about page](https://askubuntu.com/about).

To be honest, I didn't think that such great content would be in such a little *link*.

[image: screenshoot]

This page is very intuitive and it explains *how this site works* in a very nice way. It is the best page out of all the pages at introducing new users to the site.

So I think that the design of this link should be better, so that it could be differentiated from the other ones.

If this link had a different design, (I think that) newer users would go there and learn more information about the functionality of this great site.

---

Another alternative is change the title from "About" to "How this site works".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Bar for new users was added recently that states:

> Here's how it works:

And has a link directly to to the about page. This introduces new users to the basics, without *redirecting* (misleading when searching for a question from outside of the site)

[image]

So I think this already handles this problem without removing the expected functionality for other users

Comment: I didn't know about that, it helps a lot. But that message is showed after the registration of a new user, right? I mean, if you are not logged in, navigating the site, you wont see it.

Comment: It is before registration, I believe. Because I only saw it when I was not logged in on another browser.

Comment: It is before registration or logging in.  Just was welcomed (or first time noticing this box today)when opening new browser session and going to Ask Ubuntu when not logged in.  Well asked question.  @mateo_salta Nice work and well done to those involved for making  this happen.